# Node.js readStream for large data processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having trouble creating a line by line node.js method of processing large nessus xml files without high RAM usage. In its current form, it is saving data in MongoDB correctly, however the RAM usage keeps increasing, and errors out with files over ~1.5GB.

I've tried using .pause() on the readStream, however, I must have implemented it incorrectly, because it never seemed to actually pause the stream.

Here is the code:

```
// LR.JS Imports
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');
var instream = fs.createReadStream('test.nessus');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
var buff = false;
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var buffStream = '';
//Mongoose Imports
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ReportHostDoc = require('./schemas/report-host.model.js');
var ReportItemDoc = require('./schemas/report-item.model.js');
var PluginDetailDoc = require('./schemas/plugin-detail.model.js');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
// Mongoose Connect
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  // Create counters for _taskCheck
  var reportHostCounter = 0;
  var reportHostSaveCounter = 0;
  rl.on('line', (line) => {
    // process line here
    if (/[<]ReportHost/.test(line)) {
      buff = true;
      reportHostCounter++;
    }
    if (buff == true) {
      buffStream += line + '\n';
    }
    if (/[<][/]ReportHost/i.test(line)) {
      buff = false; // changed to = not == 9/6
      // XML2JS Parse ReportHost Buffstream
      parseString(buffStream, (err, result) => {
        // Loop through ReportHost properties to reliably find IP
        var reportHostIP = '';
        var reportHostOS = '';
        result.ReportHost.HostProperties[0].tag.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.$.name === 'host-ip') {
            reportHostIP = entry._;
          }
          if (entry.$.name === 'operating-system') {
            reportHostOS = entry._;
          }
        });
        // Save Report Host Document
        var host = new ReportHostDoc({
          hostname: result.ReportHost.$.name,
          ip: reportHostIP,
          os: reportHostOS,
          high: 0,
          critical: 0
        });
        // Process Each Report Item
        result.ReportHost.ReportItem.forEach((entry) => {
          var cvssScore = '';
          if (entry.cvss_base_score) {
            cvssScore = JSON.stringify(entry.cvss_base_score).slice(2, 5)
          } else {
            cvssScore = 0;
          }
          var item = new ReportItemDoc({
            itemName: entry.$.pluginName,
            pluginID: entry.$.pluginID,
            ipAddress: reportHostIP,
            exploitAvailable: entry.exploit_available,
            cvssBaseScore: cvssScore,
            pluginPublishedDate: entry.plugin_publication_date,
            pluginModifiedDate: entry.plugin_modification_date,
            description: entry.description
          })
          if (item.cvssBaseScore >= 7 && item.cvssBaseScore < 10) {
            host.high++;
          }
          if (item.cvssBaseScore == 10) {
            host.critical++;
          }
          item.save((err, item) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
          })
        });
        host.save((err, host) => {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          reportHostSaveCounter++;
        });
      })
      buffStream = ''; // Empty buffer for next report host
    }
  });
  rl.on('close', () => { // Read Stream Finished
    console.log('Log Parse finished!');
    var _taskCheck = setInterval(() => { // Async loop waits for all tasks to finish
      if (reportHostCounter == reportHostSaveCounter) {
        clearInterval(_taskCheck);
        var pluginCounter = 0;
        var pluginSaveCounter = 0;
        ReportItemDoc.distinct('pluginID', (err, ids) => {
          ids.forEach((id) => {
            pluginCounter++;
            ReportItemDoc.findOne({
              'pluginID': id
            }, (err, plugin) => {
              ReportItemDoc.count({
                'pluginID': id
              }, (err, count) => {
                var pluginSeverity = '';
                var cvss = plugin.cvssBaseScore;
                if (cvss >= 7 && cvss < 10) {
                  pluginSeverity = 'High';
                }
                if (cvss == 10) {
                  pluginSeverity = 'Critical';
                }
                item = new PluginDetailDoc({
                  pluginName: plugin.itemName,
                  pluginID: id,
                  severity: pluginSeverity,
                  quantity: count,
                  description: plugin.description
                })
                item.save((err, host) => {
                  if (err) return console.log(err);
                  pluginSaveCounter++;
                });
              })
            });
          })
        })
        var _pluginTaskCheck = setInterval(() => { // Async loop waits for all tasks to finish
          if (pluginCounter == pluginSaveCounter) {
            clearInterval(_pluginTaskCheck);
            mongoose.connection.close();
          }
        }, 100);
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend abandoning this current plan and checking into a streaming XML parser that does all this for you.  I can't recommend a specific module... there are a few... but they're very good at what you're doing, pulling individual objects out of an XML stream.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm actually using an xml parser. the problem is, I can't parse the whole file into it since the files are so huge. I'm asynchronously piecemeal-parsing every <ReportHost> element. However, clearly I'm doing in an efficient manner.

Comment: Not just an XML parser.... a **streaming** XML parser.

Comment: https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream  https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-object-stream